# Does Weight Gaining Workout Stunt Growth?

Tags: workout, weight-gain

Hi I'm 16 years and 10months old. My height is 5'5'' and weight is only 47kg.
I'm too much thin so that I haven't any girlfriend. I want to be healthy. I want to start weight gaining workout. But I'm worried about it. Because I want to be taller also. Everybody telling that this could stunt my growth...

Does weight gaining workout stunt growth????

And please also tell that which kinds of home workout I can do for weight gain. Now I'm eating too much and doing 10x3=30 push-ups daily. And doing pull-up also.

Comment: _Does weight gaining workout stunt growth?_  Any reason why you think it would?

Comment: Because I'm not so tall, so I don't want to lost any chance......
I'm worried about heavy lifting....

Comment: Your genetics, rather than weight training, are going to determine your potential for growth.  Lifting weights will not stop you from growing taller.

Answer (score 2):

**Does weight gaining workout stunt growth?**

**No**. **Improper form causes stunt growth**. You are only 16, you are still growing, so stop worrying about your height. I agree with rrirower statement, that is your **height is determined by your genetics**.

Now, as for a home workout, there are probably a lot of routines on the net.
Here are a few to help.

[Buff Dudes Home Workout Routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqgGhJywnHI)

[Barstarzz Home Workout Routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnj9WD6F8-Q)

[Nerd Fitness Home Workout Routine](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/12/09/beginner-body-weight-workout-burn-fat-build-muscle/)

With that said, I **highly recommend doing some sort of strength training routine** to build up your strength. Once you are satisfied with the weights you can lift, either continue doing the same strength training routine or your own split or doing a different strength / hypertrophy routine.

Answer (score 1):

Height is largely determined by your genetics, though childhood nutrition, stress and health play a part in determining your maximum adult height. If you're after a rough idea of this figure there are a number of calculators that can approximate your potential height eg.

- [Height Calculator](http://www.calculator.net/height-calculator.html)
- [Height Predictor](http://www.babycenter.com/child-height-predictor)

Anyway as your current BMI is below the minimum (18) recommended by the World Health Organization, and the ideal 22.5, proposed in a number of studies, gaining weight may help you reach your potential height.

As to exercise, as long as the exercise isn't combined with calorie restriction / malnutrition there isn't any evidence it restricts growth in fact the contrary has been found, with a correlation shown between moderate exercise and bone growth.

See:

- [Are There Exercises that Stunt Children's Growth?](http://www.livestrong.com/article/441421-a-list-of-exercises-that-stunt-childrens-growth/)
- [Can Lifting Weights When Young Stunt Your Growth?](http://www.livestrong.com/article/430166-can-lifting-weights-when-young-stunt-your-growth/)

Answer (score 1):

Lifting weights with proper form while maintaining a healthy diet will not stunt growth. In fact, weight lifting has many benefits for youths including increased strength for sports and higher self-esteem. (1) (2) (3)

1 [Misconceptions About Training Youth, Knowledge To Share With Parents And Administrators, Lon Kilgore PhD](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Weightlifting/YouthMisconceptions.html)

2 [Strength training in children and adolescents, Center for Sports Medicine at Saint Francis Memorial Hospital, Webb DR.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2216562)

3 [Resistance training, skeletal muscle and growth. The Ribstein Center for Sport Medicine Sciences and Research, Falk B1, Eliakim A.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16437017)